# A list with 70 MB on disk but 500MB in memory

Tags: python, list

I have a python list of string tuples of the form: `lst = [('xxx', 'yyy'), ...etc]`. The list has around `8154741` tuples. I used a profiler and it says that the list takes around 500 MB in memory. 
Then I wrote all tuples in the list into a text file and it took around 72MB on disk size.

I have three questions:

- Why the memory consumption is different from disk usage?
- And is it logical to consume 500MB of memory for such a list?
- Is there a way/technique to reduce the size of the list?

Comment: related: [How many bytes per element are there in a Python list (tuple)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/135664/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have `8154741` tuples, that means your list, assuming 8 byte pointers, already contains `62 MB` of pointers to tuples.
Assuming each tuple contains two ascii strings in python2, thats another `124 MB` of pointers for each tuple.
Then you still have the overhead for the tuple and string objects, each object has a reference count, assuming that is a 8 byte integer you have another `186 MB` of reference count storage. That is already `372 MB` of overhead for the `46 MB` of data you would have with two 3 byte long strings in size 2 tuples.
Under python3 your data is unicode and may be larger than 1 byte per character too.

So yes it is expected this type of structure consumes an large amount of excess memory.

If your strings are all of similar length and the tuples all have the same length a way to reduce this is to use numpy string arrays. They store the strings in one continuous memory block avoiding the object overheads. But this will not work well if the strings vary in size a lot as numpy does not support ragged arrays.

```
>>> d = [("xxx", "yyy") for i in range(8154741)]
>>> a = numpy.array(d)
>>> print a.nbytes/1024**2
46
>>> print a[2,1]
yyy
```

Comment: I noticed that accessing a numpy array is slower than accessing python lists, why?

Comment: numpy is optimized for applying common operations on large sets of elements at once, accessing single elements is not very well optimized and has large overheads. If it is too slow you could use numpy only a storage container and extract memory friendly chunks into pure python structures for processing.

Answer (score 2):

Python objects can take much more memory than the raw data in them. This is because to achieve the features of Python's advanced and superfast data structures, you have to create some intermediate and temporary objects.
Read more [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/python-memory-management.html).

Working around this issue has several ways, see a case study [here](http://guillaume.segu.in/blog/code/487/optimizing-memory-usage-in-python-a-case-study/). In most cases, it is enough to find the best suitable python data type for your application (would it not be better to use a numpy array instead of a list in your case?). For more optimizing, you can move to Cython where you can directly declare the types (and so, the sizes) of your variables, like in C.

There are also packages like [IOPro](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/iopro/) that try to optimize memory usage (this one is commercial though, does anyone know a free package for this?).

Answer (score 0):

Well are the strings mostly shared or unique?
What is the significance of the tuples: bag-of-words or skip-gram representation?
If so, one good library for vector representations of words is [word2vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/)

and here's a good [article on optimizing word2vec's performance](http://radimrehurek.com/2013/09/word2vec-in-python-part-two-optimizing/)

Do you actually need to keep your string contents in-memory, or can you just convert to a vector of features, and write the string<->feature correspondence to disk?