# Should I store categorical variables as integers or letters in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to represent the sequence of a biological virus as `ATGC`s, but I have seen code where it is represented as `1234`s instead. Are there any differences in memory usage or code speed if we store it as the integers `[1,2,3,4]` instead of the letters `[A,T,G,C]`?

For those who might need a bit more context, I will not be doing any mathematical operations on the string of numbers/letters apart from changing their identities at random positions (i.e. mutation), keeping track of the positions that are mutated away from a reference sequence in a dictionary (such as: `{2:'G', 52:'A'}` or `{2:3, 52:1}`), and exporting the full sequence of any biological virus strain by iterating over the reference sequence and checking the mutation dictionary for any mutations.

Comment: If used as indices in a list lookups are faster and storage is more compact. In a dictionary, not so much.

Comment: See also this answer about measuring memory sizes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/136083/699224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of strings or integers depends on the size of your DNA sequence. I know that some sequences might be over millions of elements.
It is better to use typed integers if you are dealing with a lot of information. Otherwise, you can use strings if it is more suitable for you.